# Travelling to Norway for a month

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, norway

I will be travelling to Norway for a month. I have never been to Europe before. I have a few questions:

1. Will my Visa branded cards work in Norway?
2. How difficult will it be to take a 2-3 day trip to Sweden?
3. What is the cost of living in Norway?

I **assume** that I will be able to use my Visa branded cards just as long as I tell my bank that I will be traveling, and make sure that they are "enabled" or "unblocked" to work overseas.
I **assume** that I can take a few days trip to Sweden on a temporary traveler's visa, would I apply at the airport before I fly to Sweden?
I **assume** that the cost of living is roughly equivalent to my area of the US (Washington). So, I am planning to have about 100$-130$ daily allowance, and I am also planning to be as frugal as possible; this means staying at hostels and eating out as little as possible.

How far off are my assumptions?

Comment: Which country issued your passport?

Comment: You should split this up in three different questions. The third is however opinion based and is likely to be closed.

Comment: Once you're in Norway you'll be inside the Schengen zone, and you can then hop back and forth across the border with Sweden to your heart's content without any further visa or immigration formalities.

Comment: Your first question is a duplicate of this one, although I disagree with jpatokal's answer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8066/can-one-use-bank-of-america-cards-in-norway/8076#8076

Comment: I have a US issued passport

Comment: You should split this in to seperate questions. (Although no.3 will be closed as "opnion based" - diffefrent people live very differently. Cost of being a tourist is also not the same as cost of living.  Finally, some of your assumptions are **way** off, and you should consult the State Department's travel advice pages before going anywhere, or you are going to get in to trouble on future trips re: visas.

Comment: @Ace since you have a US passport, you do not need a visa to visit the Schengen area, which includes both Norway and Sweden.  There's therefore nothing to apply for at the airport.  This visa-free arrangement allows you to be in the Schengen area for up to 90 days in any 180-day period.